# Message: Unable to locate elemen?

Tags: python, selenium

'''from selenium import webdriver

def instaboot():

```
url =("https://www.instagram.com/")
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
log_in =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']")
```

instaboot()'''

'''error:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[@href='/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher']'''`